# Shipping and Handling no longer transferring to Paypal from Drupal 6.x - Ubercart

Tags: drupal, paypal, drupal-6, ubercart

Since the rollout of the new Paypal webhooks for REST API's this week. Paypal is no longer recognising the shipping and handling from our Drupal 6.x site. We are using Drupal Core,  shipping, Ubercart and Paypal modules.

Does something need to be patched in our modules to ensure that it will work?

Answer (score 0):

Answer form PayPal Tech Support:

"... the shipping and handling cost calculator is broken. The fix will be productive today. "

So just wait